# How I can assign cURL Response value to a variable in Github Actions

Tags: json, curl, github-actions

I'm a novice at YAML/CURL and Github Actions, so I was trying to assign a variable on the YML, and I was trying to assign a key value from a JSON response generated by cURL. I tried to put the JSON response into a file via *-o* and assign this file's information to a variable, but wasn't successful at all. Maybe the way I am doing it is wrong, but I simply don't know.

Here is an example of one of my attempts:

```
curl -u ${{ secrets.test1 }}/token:${{ secrets.test2 }} "https://test/api/v2/blablabla/test" -o Data.json 
info="$(<Data.json).info" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

I tried  to do this way too:

```
info = "$(curl -u ${{ secrets.test1 }}/token:${{ secrets.test2 }} 'https://test/api/v2/blablabla/test' | jq -r 'info.blablabla')"
```

I don't know how I would assign it, I tried with these ways and some others, but I suddenly don't know how I would do that. Any solution for me is satisfactory. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

There are Bash issues with your approach, independent of Actions; you can't have blanks around the `=` in assignments:

```bash
info=$(...)
```

Then, you likely control the secrets yourself, but it's generally good practice to set values from Actions contexts in the environment, and then reference the environment variables:

```yaml
- env:
    user: ${{ secrets.test1 }}
    pass: ${{ secrets.test2 }}
  run: |
    curl -u "$user/token:$pass" ...
```

This helps prevent [shell injection attacks](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions#understanding-the-risk-of-script-injections).

Lastly, setting multi-line output parameters has historically been quite finicky, but it's quite straightforward now: you have to use a here-doc. The [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#example-of-a-multiline-string) shows how to do it for an environment variable, but it works just the same for output parameters:

```bash
{
    echo "param<<EOF"
    curl wttr.in?format=j1
    echo "EOF"
} >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
```

This'll make the output of the curl command available in the `param` output parameter.

If you're not sure about the contents of the here-doc, you might want to persist the output to a file and then read that file instead of passing around a parameter (current recommendation in documentation), or you could use a randomized delimiter (previously recommended):

```bash
# Generate 8 random uppercase characters
delim=$(tr -dc '[:upper:]' < /dev/urandom | head -c8)
{
    echo "param<<$delim"
    curl wttr.in?format=j1
    echo "$delim"
} >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
```

Taken all together, for your case, assuming the JSON payload won't contain a string `EOF` on its own line, you could do something like this:

```yaml
- name: Set info output parameter
  id: setinfo
  env:
    user: ${{ secrets.test1 }}
    pass: ${{ secrets.test2 }}
  run: |
    {
        echo "info=<<EOF"
        curl -u "$user/token:$pass" 'https://test/api/v2/blablabla/test' \
            | jq -r 'info.blablabla'
        echo "EOF"
    } >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
```