# How can I assign the output from a cURL command, to another command in GitHub Actions?

Tags: github-actions, jira-rest-api

I am attempting to create a jira ticket and then create a Microsoft Teams notification including the ticket reference using cURL in a GitHub Action as follows:

```
- name: Create Jira Ticket
        id: create-ticket
        run: |
          echo === Create Jira Ticket ===
          curl --request POST \
          --url 'https://ORG.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue' \
          --header 'Authorization: Basic ENCODED_STRING' \
          --header 'Accept: application/json' \
          --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
          --data '{"fields":{"project":{"key": "KEY"},"summary": "TEST_TICKET","description": {"type": "doc","version": 1,"content": [{"type": "paragraph","content": [{"text": "CREATING_TEST_TICKET","type": "text"}]}]},"issuetype": {"name": "Task"}}}'

- name: Teams Notification with Jira Ticket ID
  if: always() #&& steps.create-ticket.outcome == 'success'
  run: |
    echo === Create Teams Notification ===
    curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"text": "TICKET_DETAIL "}' \
    ${{ secrets.MSTEAMS_WEBHOOK }}
```

The ticket is creating successfully, however I have not been able to output the issue id or key, which is included in the cURL output in the GitHub Action, shown below:

```
Run echo === Create Jira Ticket ===
=== Create Jira Ticket ===
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   242    0     0  100   242      0   1168 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1169
100   344    0   102  100   242     86    206  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   293
{"id":"XXXXX","key":"XXX-XXXX","self":"https://ORG.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/XXXXX"}
```

I have tried assign the output of the command to a defined variable/GITHUB_OUTPUT/GITHUB_ENV and also using a multiline approach. For example, the following multiline attempt returns two different errors:

```
run: |
  {
    echo "info=<<EOF"
    curl --request POST \
    --url 'https://ORG.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue' \
    --header 'Authorization: Basic ENCODED_STRING' \
    --header 'Accept: application/json' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data '{"fields":{"project":{"key": "KEY"},"summary": "TEST_TICKET","description": {"type": "doc","version": 1,"content": [{"type": "paragraph","content": [{"text": "CREATING_TEST_TICKET","type": "text"}]}]},"issuetype": {"name": "Task"}}}'
    echo "EOF"
  } >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
```

```
Error: Unable to process file command 'output' successfully.
Error: Invalid format '{"id":"XXXXX","key":"XXX-XXXX","self":"https://ORG.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/XXXXX"}EOF'
```

Is it possible to output the values of "id":"XXXXX" or "key":"XXX-XXXX" from the curl response, so they can replace TICKET_DETAIL in the Teams notification step, and actually appear in the teams notification?

Comment: I just recently answered something very similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77223961/3266847), does that help?

Comment: Is the closing `EOF` alone on one line, without whitespace?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I attempted this yesterday but it's throwing two errors that I am not certain how to resolve. The curl command is now surrounded by:  
`{echo "info=<<EOF"...} >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"`  
New errors:  
`Error: Unable to process file command 'output' successfully.
Error: Invalid format '{"id":"XXXXX","key":"XXX-XXXX","self":"https://ORG.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/XXXXX"}EOF'` 
Any suggestions on how to resolve these?

Comment: Yes. It follows the final line of the curl command on the next line, and the line after closes the } and assigns to $GITHUB_OUTPUT:

`--data '{"fields":{"project":{"key": "KEY"},"summary": "TEST_TICKET","description": {"type": "doc","version": 1,"content": [{"type": "paragraph","content": [{"text": "CREATING_TEST_TICKET","type": "text"}]}]},"issuetype": {"name": "Task"}}}'  
            echo "EOF"
          } >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"`

Comment: The comment formatting unfortunately does away with all the whitespace, so I can't tell what exactly your code looks like.

Comment: Oh, I actually see it. I think the curl output ends without a newline. What happens if you insert an `echo ""` before `echo "EOF"`?

Comment: Adding the echo "" fixed it. Thanks so much for your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Save the output of `curl` in the variable:

```
VAR_NAME=$(command-to-run)
```

Then use this variable to print to `$GITHUB_OUTPUT`

```
- id: create-ticket
  run: |
    echo === Create Jira Ticket ===

    RESULT=$(curl --request POST \
    --url 'https://ORG.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue' \
    --header 'Authorization: Basic ENCODED_STRING' \
    --header 'Accept: application/json' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data '{"fields":{"project":{"key": "KEY"},"summary": "TEST_TICKET","description": {"type": "doc","version": 1,"content": [{"type": "paragraph","content": [{"text": "CREATING_TEST_TICKET","type": "text"}]}]},"issuetype": {"name": "Task"}}}')

    echo "result=$RESULT" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"

- run: echo Result from the prev step: "${{ steps.create-ticket.outputs.result }}"
```

You can then use `fromJSON()` to read individual fields of the response

```
- run: echo Ticket id: ${{ fromJSON(steps.create-ticket.outputs.result).id }}
```